# "Ownerless" (no permission) SSD-friendly filesystem

Tags: permissions, filesystem, usb-drive, ssd

A bit of context and needs:

- Most time I'm using Ubuntu machines.
- I have a laptop which I do not carry around a lot, so I'm in usermode (no admin permissions) lots of time.
- I have a large and fast 64GB pendrive which I would like to use.
- Sometimes I use Windows, but I do not expect compatibility. Although it would be nice.

Using FAT32 seems very primitive. But using XFS (or EXT4, or...) tends to annoy because file owner and permissions and stuff. I don't know if there's a comfortable mode for that. Couldn't think any adequate BTRFS option.

Using the pendrive without admin intervention is important. I considered having two partitions FAT32 + XFS, and using the later only in my own computers and fine-tuning by hand the ownership (haven't tried XFS pendrive mounting). But it seems a pain in the a** set-up.

Any ideas? Has somebody done something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it offers anything over FAT32 except file sizes but I use NTFS when I need to meet all those conditions.

I just created one in GParted and tested all the scenarios you mention and it seemed to work fine.  The recommendation is that once you do this you need to make sure you "Safely eject" on Windows machines, which I think may be more forgiving on FAT32.